# Как в swing jlabel изменить цвет конкретной буквы строки

Tags: java, строки, swing, color

Идея такая: есть JLabel который выводит слова из листа строк(ArrayList). Необходимо изменить цвет каждой 4 буквы. Как это можно реализовать? Например сделать эту букву красной?

Comment: Вам нужно будет переопределить метод отрисовки JLabel. Стандартными средствами никак

Comment: Не могли бы вы более подробно рассказать как это можно сделать, или хотя бы кинуть ссылку на нормальную статью?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, в данной задаче действительно лучше использовать html-разметку. Переопределение `paintComponent` кажется излишним усложнением. Спасибо [denis-e](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116707/271740) за ссылку.

```
String s = "Hello, world!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<html>");
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  if (i % 4 == 3) {
    sb.append("<font color=red>");
  } else {
    sb.append("<font color=black>");
  }
  sb.append(s.charAt(i)).append("</font>");
}
sb.append("</html>");
JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(sb.toString());
```

Логика отрисовки компонент в Swing довольно сложна. Вот [резюме](https://ipsoftware.ru/posts/paint/#%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-swing-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B5) в статье на русском, [статья](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) и [официальный туториал](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) от Oracle на английском. Вкратце, можно переопределить метод `paintComponent`, но есть нюансы. Вот пример кода.

```
class MyLabel extends JLabel {

  public MyLabel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,50));
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    char[] text = getText().toCharArray();
    int baseline = getHeight() - 5;
    int x = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if (i % 4 == 3) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
      } else {
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      }
      graphics.drawChars(text, i, 1, x, baseline);
      x += 9;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! это не помогло мне с моей задачей, но только лишь потому, что у меня пока не хватает знаний. Пойду разбираться)))

Answer (score 1):

Создаёте свой класс, наследуя от стандартного, и расширяете:

```
public class ColorfullLabel extends JLabel{

    private String text;

    public ColorfullLabel () {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //  ваша логика отрисовки
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

Text это ваш текст для лейбела, который вы хотите перекрашивать.

Можно попробовать так - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225602/how-to-change-the-color-of-particular-characters-in-jlabel
, но в моем случае так не работало.

Comment: Зачем `setText` переопределять? Так не будет автоматической перерисовки.

Comment: Сделал по вашему методу(через html тэги), все получилось

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал при помощи костыля в виде html тэгов. Вот код:

```
JLabel label = new Jlabel();
ArrayList<String> someArray = new ArrayList<>();
// выводим каждый элемент массива
someArray.forEach(element -> {
    // задаем индекс буквы, которую необходимо покрасить
    int redChar = 4;
    // Создаем временную строку для покраски символа в красный
    String tempChar = String.valueOf(element.charAt(redChar));
    //красим символ в красный
    tempChar = "<font color=red>" + tempChar + "</font>";
    // Собираем элемент в одну целую строку
    element = element.substring(0, redChar) + tempChar + element.substring(redChar + 1);
    // Добавляем тэг <html> к элементу, чтобы swing понял что это надо обрабатывать как html
    label.setText("<html>"+ element+ "</html>");
});
```

Понятно что это костыль. Думаю для более нормальной реализации придется углубится в swing и методы JLabel чтобы переопределять их как мне надо. Всем спасибо за советы и подсказки!